# How to traverse through a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to json and arrays and objects. So this may be a very trivial doubt. I have an array of the structure:

```
[{
"A": {"key11": 10, "key12": 20, "key13": 30},
"B": {"key21": 10, "key22": 20},
"C": {"key31": 10, "key32": 20, "key33": 30, "key34": 40}
}]
```

I am accessing the data via an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'somepath/fileName.json',
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false,
    type : 'get',
    success : function(data) 
      {
       MyData = data;
      },
    error : function() {
       alert("error");
      }
});
```

Now my MyData contains an Object of the above mentioned data. I need to access A,B,C but my question is whether its possible to access them using positions?
Kindly help. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it is possible to access them using position, but that would be bad way. Ideal way is `data[0].A`

Comment: to loop through this use Object.keys(obj[0]).forEach(function(key) {
 alert(obj[0][key])
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Using `async: false` is deprecated and in the process of being removed from jQuery. Use asynchronous calls instead.

Comment: *I am new to json* Then you should start off by learning what JSON is, and is not. What you are talking about is a JavaScript array, **not** JSON.

Comment: `A`, `B` and `C` have no position. Properties in an object are unordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question title this is how you traverse through your JavaScript Array using `$.each`

```js
var data = [{
    "A": {
      "key11": 10,
      "key12": 20,
      "key13": 30
    },
    "B": {
      "key21": 10,
      "key22": 20
    },
    "C": {
      "key31": 10,
      "key32": 20,
      "key33": 30,
      "key34": 40
    }
  }];


$.each(data, function() {
    $.each(this, function(outerkey, outervalue) {
        console.log(outerkey);
        $.each(this, function(innerkey, innervalue) {
            console.log(innerkey + '=' + innervalue);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JSON Traverse</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you only want to access **Key** (A,B,C)

```
$.each(first, function(key, value) {
    $('#results').append("  " + key + " ");
});
```

If you want a **specific key** and you know the index then you can use `Object` aswell

```
var result = Object.keys(data[0]); 
console.log(result[0]); //this will return 'A'
```

Comment: Note, jQuery is not necessary here. You can also use `Array.forEach`